# is it possible to use lucene(on linux) and asp.net(on windows) at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, lucene

I want to start a new project I need performance as well as a neat  and robust GUI

about the performance I have around 2 millions documents which I like to index'em by the help of lucene installed on linux due to its performance and security.

and about GUI I'd like to have flexible and professional look website and since I'm experienced with .net I'd like to retrieve the lucene's result and show it in my own way.

I've heard about some RESTful services available inside the lucene but I don't have any clue according to that and how to connect these two together.

how can I connect asp.net to lucene?

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option: Install [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on Linux. Solr is a nice search server built based on Lucene that supports REST-like XML and JSON APIs. ASP can parse JSON and from there you can build your own front end in ASP.net.

Comment: you mean I have to install lucene then solr on top of that?

Comment: No. You just install Solr. It will bring Lucene along.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene has been ported to .Net.  http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

We use it for our website to index various things, and these indexes are in the millions too.  If you're wanting to use Linux in the belief that it's more efficient, then it's not a matter of the choice of OS but of accessing a remote Lucene system.

Comment: yeah I know lucene.net exists but I want to run lucene under linux as a safe and fast engine for my indexing and distill its result into asp.net and create whatever I want , say a hierarchical search engine or an enterprise document manager etc...
I do believe in power of asp.net to build such those things but I don't believe in MS windows performance.
can you explain more about your situation ? have you installed lucene.net on MS windows server? and does it have the performance just like linux? 
just for your record right now we are using index server and asp.net

Comment: I'm not getting into a 'is linux more efficient than windows' discussion.  This isn't the place and it will only start a flame war.  Yes, we Lucene.net it installed on a Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to install Solr, and use Solr.NET to interface with it. [SolrNET](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) is a .NET client for Solr (the most important).

It's possible to install Solr both on Linux or Windows. And easy way to install Solr on windows is using this [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/solr), which installs the server, as well as the Solr servlet.

It's also possible to use [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch), and some of the [available .NET clients](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/clients.html#community-dotnet).

**NOTE on Lucene.NET:** it's a port of the original Java Lucene to .NET, available at Nuget, but it's dead: the latest ported version is 3.0.3, while as of april 2015 the Lucene (and Solr) is version 5.1. So, if you want to use the newest functionalities, it's much better to install Solr (on Windows or Linux) and use Solr.NET as explained above.